# How to add Name: before name and $ before numbers in a .txt file in c++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this:

I have to read from a .txt file that contains a name on one line, then a price on the next line, and continues about 10 times. (i.e. the text file says:

John Doe

234.0

Jane Doe

465.0

I have to print out "Name " in front of the name and "wage: " in front of the number. How would I do this? I don't even know where to start!

EDIT: What I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
ifstream infile("wage.txt");
ofstream outfile("wage.txt");
string line;
if(infile.is_open){
    while(!infile){
        getline(infile,line);
        if (isdigit(line)){
            cout<<"$"<<line<<endl;
    }
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the input file

Comment: Not to be rude, but is this homework?

Comment: @linux yes, sorry, it is homework, I forgot to add that tag

Comment: Basic file I/O to get you started http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: @user1443074 - You are more likely to get an answer if you try something yourself and publish the code with the problem(s) that you are experiencing.

Comment: ...and `ifstream infile("...");` isn't much.

Comment: edited...what is the c++ equivalent to python's .isdigit?

Comment: Are you sure you must modify `wages.txt`, and not, say, create a new output file?

Comment: I'm guessing that would be the best way to do it, is to create a new output file, thats why i added the outfile>>"$">>>>line>>endl;

Comment: @user1443074: Look up the string functions, they are online: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: @user1443074: Reading and writing from the same file could lead to unpredictable results. Read from one file and write to another. Rename after all writing is finished, if necessary.

Comment: oh goodness...i misread the description of what he wants...he just wants us to output the 
Name:---
wage:---.--
he doesnt want us to write it to another file :/ just print it out

Comment: cout goes the other way. `cout << "text" << endl;`

Comment: @user1443074 I think he needs to output to a file since he's using ofstream.. Just guessing though.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, that of course depends on if you really understood what your questions requirements are.

Comment: how do i use isdigit? i keep getting an error message

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 90% sure that you're going to have to read in the entire text file, and then completely over-write it.
A text file is essentially a sequence of characters, and I don't believe that they support actual insertions.

There are multiple approaches that you can take, I'd probably load up the file into some structure containing names and amounts, and then regenerate the file with the proper format.

Another approach would be to create a new file, and build it up based on the old file, except with the correct formatting, and then delete the old file and rename the new one to have the proper name.